# Write a MIPS program where you prompt the user for name and then puting it in a sentance that says hello (his name)

Tags: assembly, mips, prompt

Write a MIPS program where you prompt the user for his name.
Then, print the following message
“Welcome to COE301,  ”
Assume the maximum length for a name is 20 characters.

.data

name : .asciiz "Welcome to COE301, "
prompt: .asciiz "Enter your name: "

.text

li $v0, 8
la $a0, name
li $a1, 20
syscall

what should I do next???

.data

name : .asciiz "Welcome to COE301, "
prompt: .asciiz "Enter your name: "

.text

li $v0, 8
la $a0, name
li $a1, 20
syscall

what should i do?

Comment: Find and study a MIPS sample program.  There's tons of them online.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you want to format your code for better readability on on this site you can start a paragraph with three backticks (the key to the left of the 1 key).